# Только начинаю.... получать боль.:()

Tags: javascript

```
/*
В переменной data хранится такой массив:
[
  {name: "Саша", age: 19},
  {name: "Катя", age: 21},
  {name: "Миша", age: 17},
  {name: "Федя", age: 23},
  {name: "Клава", age: 22}
]
*/

function calcAvgAge(array) {
  // Напишите код здесь
}
```

***Помогите решить, я не могу понять, как взять значение из обЪекта data.age!
Вообщем тут нужно посчитать средний***

Comment: Товарищ, напишите, что вам уже удалось. А то выглядит, что как будто вы ждёте, что за вас всю работу сделают.

Comment: const nums = data.reduce((total, amount) => {
  amount.age.forEach( num => {
      total.push(num );
  })
  return total;
}, [])

Comment: Пытаюсь зайти примерно вот такой конструкцией,

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо пройтись по каждому элементу массива, при этом сохраняя сумму возврастов.

```
сумма = 0
Для каждого человека сделать:
   к сумме прибавить человек.возраст
После сумму поделить на общее кол-во человек
```

```js
const data = [
  {name: "Саша", age: 19},
  {name: "Катя", age: 21},
  {name: "Миша", age: 17},
  {name: "Федя", age: 23},
  {name: "Клава", age: 22}
];

function calcAvgAge(array) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const person of array) {
    sum += person.age;
  }
  return sum / array.length;
}

console.log(calcAvgAge(data));
```

Если красиво, то:

```js
const a = [
  {name: "Саша", age: 19},
  {name: "Катя", age: 21},
  {name: "Миша", age: 17},
  {name: "Федя", age: 23},
  {name: "Клава", age: 22}
];

console.log(a.reduce((ac,c)=>ac+=c.age,0)/a.length);
```